# Pass select statements into SQL Server function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I don't know if this is possible, but I was wondering if it was possible to pass a  SQL Server `SELECT` statement into a SQL Server custom function. I need to be able to compare the data in any table with an intersect and return the tables that have data the same.

However, the tables I will need to do this on will all have a variety of columns. I need to compare 20 different tables that I format how I need. Is this a possibility? Is it possible to just throw a `#tableVar` into a function or stored procedure?

Here is what I am doing now for a manual process, the `Select` statements have been modified slightly for security:

```
Select * into #tableFirst FROM [dbo].~scrubed~
where insertdate >= '2016-09-05' and InsertDate < '2016-09-06';
Select * into #tableSecond FROM [dbo].~scrubed~
where insertdate >= '2016-09-06' and InsertDate < '2016-09-07';

select onion.* into #tableIntersect from (
Select * from #tableFirst 
intersect Select * from #tableSecond
) as onion;
--Return Data
Select 'Row Matching' as RowMatching, * from #tableIntersect
```

Comment: can you provide code example of what you have and show example of what you want

Comment: You can't use dynamic sql inside user defined functions, and I don't see how temporary tables will help here. You can, however, use dynamic sql inside a stored procedure.

Comment: Updating the main with example of what im currently attempting

Comment: Zohar, how would i go about passing a table variable into the procedure without a set format then? I think that is my issue I'm trying to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(*), a.column1, a.column2 from (
select * from [dbo].~scrubed~
union all
select * from [dbo].~scrubed~) a
group by a.column1, a.column2
having count(*) > 1
```

Results for above query has matched.